# Drag and drop widget always inserts image

Tags: plugins

I am drag and dropping a widget into a section using Elementor plugin. But it does not matter, which widget I am choosing, somehow always an image gets inserted. Am I doing something wrong? I am new to wordpress and this is my first experience :(.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error seems Browser-related, as it works as expected using Firefox instead of Chrome.